# nosuid для каталога через fstab

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

У параноиков модно вешать всякие разные опции вроде `nosuid` типа для защиты от злых хакеров, вот и я решил попробовать повесить на `/home`, который не находится на отдельной файловой системе:

```
$ sudo mount --bind /home /home
$ sudo mount -o remount,nosuid /home
$ mount | grep /home
/dev/mapper/lvm-root on /home type ext4 (rw,nosuid,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Вот так это работает. Проблема в том, что при попытке прописать это в `/etc/fstab` это не работает:

```
$ sudo umount /home  # Убираем старый ручной bind
$ echo '/home /home none bind,nosuid 0 2' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
$ sudo reboot  # Или просто sudo mount /home
$ mount | grep /home
/dev/mapper/lvm-root on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Что я делаю не так? Есть ли более красивые варианты осуществить желаемое, кроме как вешать remount-скрипт в автозагрузку?

Дело происходит в Ubuntu с systemd, если вдруг это важно. Написать mount-юнит тоже пробовал, тоже не работает.

Comment: У параноиков ещё модно /home держать на крипторазделе. Совместите — перенесите /home в криптоконтейнер-файл и монтируйте его сразу с nodev и nosuid.